# script# registerScript problems with Ext#

Tags: script#

I am trying to use extsharp (on codeplex) with the latest script# and am stalled

On the end of ExtJS.Scripts.debug.js (generated by script# from the extsharp library) is a line

```
ss.loader.registerScript('ExtJS.Scripts', [core], executeScript);
```

firstly there is nothing called 'core' in scope. Second looking at ssloader.debug.ls (which is the thing that has registrScript in it) there is nothing called 'loader' but there is a function on ss called registerScript. So I changed this line to

```
ss.registerScript('ExtJS.Scripts', [], executeScript);
```

Now I at least get my Ext.OnReady function called. But its clear that the meat of ExtJS.Scripts.debug.js has not been executed (all of the objects and functions set up there dont exist). I have reached my limit of how script# works, any ideas?

PS: nikhil - pls open source script#

EDIT: Multiple layers of confusion here

a) The extsharp project is setup as a s# library (which means app) as opposed to an import library - which is what v0.7 of s# seems to want (but in fact does not work - see another SO question on that topic)

b) ext# was written using an older version of s# that did usethe registerscript function

I am still stuck but have a better understanding of why I am stuck :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the sources relevant for digging deeper into this issue - the scripts, and the project templates, the import libraries, the msbuild tasks/target etc are all on github in source form at https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp.

The lines of script above are coming from the script template (look inside the Properties folder of your project) and the script template can be customized to your need without modifying the script# compiler itself.

The latest versions of script# no longer use the constructs above. If you create a new project, you'll see a new script template that doesn't use registerScript etc.

ssloader.js is optional - it provides a script loader that does dependency checking etc. Core used to refer to mscorlib.js which is still needed.

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: I am sure I dont need the compiler source for this - just asking for it like I do everytime. So should there be a .js file generated by an import library (such as ExtJS.Scripts)? If so how do I make it happen? I started a new s# imp library project and imported all the extsharp source code; but I dont get tje .js file - which I am sure I must need

Comment: An import library represents a header file of sorts you use to define existing APIs (dom, other script frameworks etc.) so you can reference them in c# and the c# code can compile. An imported lib project doesn't generate any script - in your case you already have the ExtJS script - all you need to do in the import lib is to define what is going to be available at runtime by virtue of including the Ext script into your page.

Comment: there is a bug tho. If the import library defines types that need JS to be emitted (Record derived types for example) it fails, . The wrapper library must be built as a script libraray and its emitted JS included in the page